# Types in a sum of a matrix's elements in C

Tags: c, matrix, types

I wrote a little program to do the sum of a matrix's elements and I noticed it works when most types are int and it doesn't when most types are unsigned char, but I don't get why.

By "working" I mean "gives the correct result", actually they both compile with no errors and no warnings (even with the -Wall command), but the "not working" code just gives a different random number as a result everytime I run it (in the unsigned char range).

This is the code that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char uchar;

int matrix_sum ();

int main (void)
{

  printf ("\nSum of a matrix's elements in a function out of the main function\n\n");

  int mat [2] [3] = { {4, 5, 0} , {1, 2, 3} };

  int sum = matrix_sum (2, 3, mat);

  printf ("Sum of matrix is: %d\n\n", sum);

  return 0;

}

int matrix_sum (int row, int col, int mat [row] [col])
{

  int sum = 0;

  for (uchar i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    for (uchar j = 0; j < col; ++j)
      sum += mat [i] [j];

  return sum;

}
```

This is the code that doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char uchar;

uchar matrix_sum ();

int main (void)
{

  printf ("\nSum of a matrix's elements in a function out of the main function\n\n");

  uchar mat [2] [3] = { {4, 5, 0} , {1, 2, 3} };

  uchar sum = matrix_sum (2, 3, mat);

  printf ("Sum of matrix is: %d\n\n", sum);

  return 0;

}

uchar matrix_sum (int row, int col, int mat [row] [col])
{

  uchar sum = 0;

  for (uchar i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    for (uchar j = 0; j < col; ++j)
      sum += mat [i] [j];

  return sum;

}
```

What rule on types did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The passed array is `uchar[2][3]`, but the array in the argument is `int[2][3]`. Here you passed different things, so it worked incorrectly.

You have two choice and should do just one of that:

1. Change the array to pass `uchar mat [2] [3]` to `int mat [2] [3]` to match the function argument.
2. Change the function argument `int mat [row] [col]` to `uchar mat [row] [col]` to match the passed thing.

Answer (score 1):

In your second code that doesn't work

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef unsigned char uchar;

uchar matrix_sum ();

int main (void)
{

  printf ("\nSum of a matrix's elements in a function out of the main function\n\n");

  //data type is uchar
  uchar mat [2] [3] = { {4, 5, 0} , {1, 2, 3} };

  //data type is uchar
  uchar sum = matrix_sum (2, 3, mat);

  printf ("Sum of matrix is: %d\n\n", sum);

  return 0;

}

//data type is uchar                data type is int
uchar matrix_sum (int row, int col, int mat [row] [col])  
//here is the reason of mismatch of the data type
{

  uchar sum = 0;

  for (uchar i = 0; i < row; ++i)
    for (uchar j = 0; j < col; ++j)
      sum += mat [i] [j];

  return sum;

}
```

Thus you just need to go to the uchar matrix_sum() function and change the data type of matrix from int to uchar.